# How to replay a transaction on classic?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, raw-transaction, replay-attack

I have looked to split and sell my etc and have successfully split with test transactions replaying on classic, however the main transaction has not replayed for 24 hours and I would like to force a replay. I have both blockchains available.

I have tried taking the output of `web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)` on ETH and tried recreating it with `ethereumjs-tx` signed and unsigned on classic without much success.

I haven't seen a method to get the raw hex of a transaction in `geth` to inject it via `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction`

My alternative is to perform the same transaction I did on ETH but on ETC

Comment: Why don't you just send the same transaction on the other chain? That seems far simpler than trying to replay

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have this tx:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1f3f3ced1fde1cbc638b3e1ba2b12d890157977208442e8686d03fc4d332225c

1. Take same input raw data and resubmit it without changing chaindId:
   Lets take Raw tx data:

https://etherscan.io/getRawTx?tx=0x1f3f3ced1fde1cbc638b3e1ba2b12d890157977208442e8686d03fc4d332225c

So we get:

`0xf8708352d1d685028fa6ae0083015f909465f4dc1a4aef2842c1ae61dfa3db7a69f25b7aff8802e45e9ccc5e1af28026a0ba87b88da31453501f9738e35d6c4f416524f92ea215d6f07b3df5f4216a41f8a0578c288d369a6f9ee073e25e745888f9099e54b604411bce1b456a6dcf3937af`

now lets try sending it to POA.network chain cURL:

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["0xf8708352d1d685028fa6ae0083015f909465f4dc1a4aef2842c1ae61dfa3db7a69f25b7aff8802e45e9ccc5e1af28026a0ba87b88da31453501f9738e35d6c4f416524f92ea215d6f07b3df5f4216a41f8a0578c288d369a6f9ee073e25e745888f9099e54b604411bce1b456a6dcf3937af"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://poa.infura.io
```

Response:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32010,"message":"Invalid chain id."},"id":1}`

It's because POA.network chain is protected with EIP-155 and doesn't allow us to send  it.

So, lets take same tx and change chainId value to resubmit tx.
which if we ask rpc server getTransactionByHash

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0x1f3f3ced1fde1cbc638b3e1ba2b12d890157977208442e8686d03fc4d332225c"],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://mainnet.infura.io | jq '.'
```

-

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "blockHash": "0x35af3597e1496acef6eb972c68243709ffc214c4b4a6f160581c4e670f67dd94",
    "blockNumber": "0x5ab068",
    "from": "0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830",
    "gas": "0x15f90",
    "gasPrice": "0x28fa6ae00",
    "hash": "0x1f3f3ced1fde1cbc638b3e1ba2b12d890157977208442e8686d03fc4d332225c",
    "input": "0x",
    "nonce": "0x52d1d6",
    "to": "0x65f4dc1a4aef2842c1ae61dfa3db7a69f25b7aff",
    "transactionIndex": "0x52",
    "value": "0x2e45e9ccc5e1af2",
    "v": "0x26",
    "r": "0xba87b88da31453501f9738e35d6c4f416524f92ea215d6f07b3df5f4216a41f8",
    "s": "0x578c288d369a6f9ee073e25e745888f9099e54b604411bce1b456a6dcf3937af"
  }
}
```

Now, lets re-send same tx onto ETC chain with `ethereumjs-tx`:
POA.network has `chainId = 99`

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const chain = 99;

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x52d1d6',
  gasPrice: '0x28fa6ae00',
  gasLimit: '0x15f90',
  to: '0x65f4dc1a4aef2842c1ae61dfa3db7a69f25b7aff',
  value: '0x2e45e9ccc5e1af2',
  data: '0x',
  chainId: chain,
  r: "0xba87b88da31453501f9738e35d6c4f416524f92ea215d6f07b3df5f4216a41f8",
  s: "0x578c288d369a6f9ee073e25e745888f9099e54b604411bce1b456a6dcf3937af",
  v: chain * 2 + 35
}


const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams)

const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
console.log('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
```

Please notice how we re-calculated `v` value:
v: chain * 2 + 35
OR you can do:
v: chain * 2 + 36
(reference: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md)

Now lets run it:
`node txGenerator.js` 
and we get

`0xf8718352d1d685028fa6ae0083015f909465f4dc1a4aef2842c1ae61dfa3db7a69f25b7aff8802e45e9ccc5e1af28081e9a0ba87b88da31453501f9738e35d6c4f416524f92ea215d6f07b3df5f4216a41f8a0578c288d369a6f9ee073e25e745888f9099e54b604411bce1b456a6dcf3937af`

so lets send it to rpc node

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["0xf8718352d1d685028fa6ae0083015f909465f4dc1a4aef2842c1ae61dfa3db7a69f25b7aff8802e45e9ccc5e1af28081e9a0ba87b88da31453501f9738e35d6c4f416524f92ea215d6f07b3df5f4216a41f8a0578c288d369a6f9ee073e25e745888f9099e54b604411bce1b456a6dcf3937af"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://poa.infura.io
```

response: 

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32010,"message":"Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 209385510302513906 and got: 0."},"id":1}`

So we have successfully changed V value, but the  account doesn't have funds to make a tx

Similar way you can use for any other CHAIN-IDs